# How to configure SSL Certificate in mobile App

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I have developed an android app where I am accessing one server url to access one xml file.In that server we have deployed one SelfSigned SSL Server Certificate. In Mobile App my code to access that xml file is-

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
```

But I am not able to configure SSL Certificate at client side i.e in my android code. Please help how to configure Client certificate in mobile app?

Comment: your mean is you can`t create https request to get the file ?

Comment: Yes..please help how to do it.I am very new  in android development